# Can Azure Point-To-Site client see default Azure DNS?

Tags: azure, dns, vpn

I have a Windows VPN client connected to an Azure Virtual Network via a Virtual Network Gateway.  Goal #1 was to connect to my virtual machine using its internal IP address.  That worked.

Second goal was to connect using its internal machine name (since the IP may change and I want no external IP address to be available).  That did not work.  There appears to be no DNS resolution occurring for my VPN client for the Azure VNET.

The VNET and the VM are both set to use the default Azure DNS for their resolution.

My question is:  Am I supposed to be able to connect using the server's name (and I therefore have something wrong)?  If not, what is the best practice for allowing connections by name in a way that will automatically adjust if the IP changes?

Comment: Can't say I'm an expert on vnets so I can't give you a straight-up answer, but I can give you a link to the article that I think describes what you can do pretty well: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances)

Comment: Yeah, I read that one.  No mention at all of VPNs.  Just VMs and Virtual Networks, for which the default DNS works just fine.  Despite hours of research, I've been unable to turn up even a single mention of DNS resolution for Point-to-Site connections, which is making me think that it just doesn't work and no one has any concerns about it.  If that's true, it's deeply disappointing on several levels.

Comment: This [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/705655/azure-vm-and-web-app-in-vnet-vpn-changing-ip-and-automatic-start-of-vpn) might also help you. It talks about Web Apps, but they use a Point-to-Site connection as well.

Comment: You *can* also make the internal IP address static.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't provide by-name access, which is my main goal, anyway.  So, it appears either no one's thought of this, or no one cares.  I'm wondering why, since access over VPN would be an appropriate function to want.

Answer (score 0):

Today we don't expose Azure's recursive DNS service over P2S or S2S connections.  It's on our long term roadmap.

Gareth